# Google play asset pack not being delivered

Tags: android, google-play, android-assetpacks

I'm publishing a game on Google Play using the bundle (aab) scheme for the first time (I've shipped a bunch of things before w/ straight apks, so I'm pretty sure the issues i'm having are with the asset pack scheme). I have it working enough so that the pre-launch report is successfully booting the app and clicking through screens in its video. But for some reason the asset pack isn't being downloaded from the store to my phone. Here's the gradle for the pack, marked as 'install-time'.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.asset-pack'

assetPack {
    packName = "assetpack"
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "install-time"
    }
}
```

I see (and feel) about 2M of data being dl'd and installed, which is the 'app' size, with the 'pack' size being about 450M.

Moreover, I can go to the bundle explorer, see the pack there, and go even farther to the 'dl the zip for the specific device' and the pack is there in the zip.

And of course *the pre-launch testing version runs and draws assets from the pack*.

I am in 'internal testing' mode still, where the app has probably never been through review by a person (and thus have the temp app name still), if that's relevant at all.  Maybe it's some scheme to avoid Google Play being used as a file server?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'fixed itself' ~24 hours later...